# How to multiply a number in a label by a certain number and output result to a different label C#

Tags: c#, label

Just struggling to figure out how to do this correctly, I have done some Googling and I have got to this point, this code does actually crash the application when I run it.

So in short, I have totalled up a bunch of numbers based on user selection (which are calculated at a Weekly rate) and I want to output the final result in a Monthly format (so * my total by 4).

Here is the code for this section that I am running, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
private void CalcButton()
    {
        double a, b, c;
        double d;


        if (double.TryParse(label41.Text, out a) && double.TryParse(label45.Text, out b) && double.TryParse(label17.Text, out c))
        {
            label43.Text = (a + b + c).ToString("C");
        }
        if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            d = double.Parse(label43.Text);
            label42.Text = (d * 4).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialize `d` to a value.
Next, if one of more of your initialize tests fail, `label43.Text` is not set and your parse of this label will fail.
I suggest, in the first test, you set the value of d to the summation of the three values and then set `level43.text` to `d.ToString("C")`
Then, you will not need to parse `label43.Text`.
Lastly, using 4 to determine a monthly amount is not accurite as there are 52 weeks per 12 months.  A closer value would be `52/12 = 4.3333 ...`

Like this:

```
private void CalcButton()
    {
        double a, b, c;
        double d = 0.0;

        if (double.TryParse(label41.Text, out a) && 
                double.TryParse(label45.Text, out b) && 
                double.TryParse(label17.Text, out c))
        {
            d = a + b + c;
            label43.Text = d.ToString("C");
        }
        if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            label42.Text = (d * 52 / 12).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks so much for your reply. That did the trick! Good catch on the monthly calculation and some really valuable insight in there. Much appreciated, Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the value is parsable first, so move it in the check would be a better option

```
private void CalcButton()
    {
        double a, b, c;
        double d;

        if (double.TryParse(label41.Text, out a) && 
            double.TryParse(label45.Text, out b) &&
            double.TryParse(label17.Text, out c))
        {
            label43.Text = (a + b + c).ToString("C");
        }

        if (radioButton4.Checked == true && 
            double.TryParse(label43.Text, out d))
        {
            label42.Text = (d * 4).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your reply. I have done as you instructed and I don't get a crash this time (progress!) but when I push the Calculate Button the label text does not change...